# Desoldering a through hole capacitor with weird terminals

Tags: soldering, electrolytic-capacitor, replacement

Apologies in advance if this is the wrong place to post this question.

So I've just RGB modded an old CRT TV, and now I'm trying to replace a series of capacitors to hopefully fix some screen geometry issues, and I've run into a little road block on a few of the larger high-voltage ones. The terminals on the underside have some sort of star-shaped grip that I've never seen before, and can't figure out how to detach them. I've been able to get some of the solder off with my vacuum desoldering gun, but I can't quite figure out the gripper part.

[image: capacitor terminal]

The replacements I bought on DigiKey (same capacitance/voltage rating, but the terminals are just thick stumps) don't have these, so I'm at a bit of a loss. Has anyone seen anything like this before? Thank you for your help.

Comment: For through hole parts with stuck legs I like to tape something heavy like a screw driver to the underside and then heat from above with hot air.

Comment: If they are actually gripping the hole then squeeze them with pliers while molten to deform them? In both axis? Then make a third pass to remove?

Comment: it could be some sort of hollow rivet.  does ot not come out whern you melt all the solder?

Comment: Jasen, you were exactly right

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Nevermind, it was just some sort of rivet inside the hole; I was assuming it was all a single piece since it didn't want to fully desolder. I just needed to up the desolder gun's temp to get it to clear the hole:

[image]

(this one's a different cap than the first picture, but it's the same deal)

Thanks all for your suggestions!

Comment: Can you please mark this as the accepted answer?

Comment: Not for 2 days, I can't

Comment: In two days would be fine. Thanks!

Comment: Interesting. Anyone any idea what the purpose of those rivets is? Is it to increase contact area and therefore decrease resistance? Or to improve mechanical strength?

Comment: I'm guessing mechanical strength, but depending how old the board is, it might be that it's double sided without plated through holes.  If it's single sided, it's almost certainly to prevent the traces from peeling up off the board.

Comment: The traces are single sided, and the board (TV) was manufactured 2003

Comment: This looks to me like either;
1.) The hole was oversized during manufacture and the insert is used to reduce hole diameter to make manufacture more successful.
2.) The insert is to reinforce the board for a heavy component to prevent damage to through hole plating/board.